# What is the most efficient way to go through string's chars in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, performance, typescript

I saw there are similar questions on SO but I didn't found one which matches my specific goal.

I have developed a small function which loops through a string (let's say between 10 and 160 chars) to extract

- wildcards (e.g. $1, $2, ...) - called "specials"
- strings between them

Example of string to parse: "word1 word2 $1 word3 $2 word4 $3".

Example of output:

```
{
    strings: [word1 word2, word3, word4],
    specialChars: 3
}
```

For sure there are also the limit cases (no wildcards, 1 wildcard only, wildcard can be at the beginning or end of the string).

The algorithm I wrote so far is as follows (there is something to fix but I am more interested in the **efficiency** than then result, in this question):

```
function parsestr(str: string) {
    let specialChars = [],
        plaintextParts = [],
        resultObject = {
            strings: [],
            specialChars: 0
        };

    // convert to char array and loop
    str.split('').forEach(function(c, i){
       if (c=='$') specialChars.push(i);
    });
    resultObject.specialChars = specialChars.length;

    // extract plain text parts
    if (specialChars.length == 0) return resultObject;

    // part before first wildcard
    if (specialChars[0]>0) plaintextParts.push(str.substr(0, specialChars[0]-1));
    // 2..N
    for (var i=1; i<specialChars.length-1; i++) {
        plaintextParts.push(str.substr(specialChars[i-1]+2, specialChars[i]-1));
    }
    // last part
    if (specialChars[specialChars.length-1]+1 < str.length-1)
        plaintextParts.push(str.substr(specialChars[specialChars.length-2]+2, specialChars[specialChars.length-1]-1));

    resultObject.strings = plaintextParts;
    return resultObject;
}

// call function and print output
var jsonString = "word1 word2 $1 word3 $2 word4 $3";
console.log(JSON.stringify(parseJsonString(jsonString)));
```

Comment: I believe this can be already done with built-in regexps in JS O_o

Comment: Yep. @MatíasFidemraizer Thats exactly how to do it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a regex:

```
let str = "word1 word2 $1 word3 $2 word4 $3";
let regex = /\$[0-9]/;
let strSplit = str.split(regex);
console.log(JSON.stringify(strSplit)); // ["word1 word2 ", " word3 ", " word4 ", ""]
```

If you do not want that last empty string you can always just s(p)lice it off.

So if you want the number of "special chars" you can just take the length of the result `strSplit` and subtract one.

Comment: just one more thing: since I need both the strings (word1 word2, word3, ...) and where (i.e. there could be 2 specials $1, $2 in a row) the specials are. how can I keep track of that?

Comment: What do you mean? Consider asking another question and letting me know

Comment: never mind. I figured it out. thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of efficiency, this seems like a micro-optimization, especially for strings no longer than 160 chars. It's more important to make your code work in a clean, understandable way than to optimize the efficiency of each operation.

When it comes to optimizing your code, try to make your general solution more efficient, and then optimize specifics later. Assuming that this function doesn't exist in a vacuum, try focusing on the performance of app itself and figure out where the actual performance bottlenecks are before optimizing something like string manipulation.